# Java xpath, select most deep children

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm new to Java and XPath syntax. I have complex xml document. What I need is to select all the nodes, that don't have children (I need their values actually).

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b>text1</b>
        <c>text2</c>
    </a>
    <d>
        <e>
            <f>text3</f>
        </e>
    </d>
    <f>text4</f>
</root>
```

I want to get list `"text1","text2","text3","text4"` here. Could you help me with XPath expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, this is, what I need

```
root.selectNodes("//*[not(*)]")
```

Answer (score 2):

> What I need is to select all the nodes, that don't have children

I suspect you mean you want to select all the elements that don't have element children. That would be `//*[not(*)]`.

Answer (score 0):

If the document is as above, try `//*/text()`  ;)

Comment: great, it works! Could you please also help me with getting these nodes names? :)

Comment: Oh, actually it works not exactly how I expect. I gets text from EACH node, but I need to get it only from those, who has no children. I mean, that I get symbols like "\n\t" from <root>, <a>, etc.